# IF/nested formula issue

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested

`=IF(AND(F2>0,F2<5),27,IF(AND(F2>4.99,F2<9),28.5,IF(AND(F2>8.99,30)))`

This is my formula.  Cell F2 has the number of years of service of an employee.  I need to calculate different pay rates per employee - 1-4 years = $27; 5-9 years=28.5; and 10+ years=30.  I keep getting an error in my formula and cannot figure out why.

Comment: What happens for F2 = 0?

Comment: Your last nested if statement `IF(AND(F2>8.99,30))` doesn't do anything. Why is that there? What result do you want if that is true and false? Furthermore, you are missing an ending parantheses. Count opening and closing as you move across +1 for opening and -1 for closing and if you don't get 0 you'll know you missed something. Try a seperate editor like `notepad++` that will highlight matching parentheses so you can track them easier in complex formulas like this (excel does this too, but it's difficult to see in that little formula window)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (assuming that F2 = 0 isn't a case to be handled separately):

```
=IF(F2 < 5,27,IF(F2 < 10,28.5,30))
```

The point is that if F2 < 5 is false -- in the else condition it is enough to just test if F2 < 10. You don't need to have something like And(F2 > 4.99, F2 < 10)

Answer (score 0):

check with this

`=IF(AND(F2>0,F2<4.99),27,IF(AND(F2>4.99,F2<9),28.5,30))`